# in ionic, when swipe back, the nav bar become blank

Tags: button, header, swipe, title, ionic-framework

the parent page:

```
<ion-view  view-title="my account" >
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive" align-title="center" ></ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content >
        <ion-list>
            <ion-item>
                <ion-item  class="item-remove-animate item-icon-left item-icon-right"  type="item-text-wrap"  ui-sref="tab.modipass">
                    <i class="icon ion-ios-unlocked-outline"></i>
                    <div>company profile</div>
                    <i class="icon ion-chevron-right icon-accessory"></i>
                </ion-item>
        </ion-list>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

the child page:

```
<ion-view  view-title="about company" on-swipe-right="closePage()">
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-assertive" align-title="center">
        <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
            <button class="button button-clear button-light" ng-click="closePage()">
                <i class="ion-ios-arrow-back" style="font-size:20px"></i>
            </button>
        </ion-nav-buttons>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <ion-content class="padding">
        <ul class="list">
            <li class="item item-text-wrap item-borderless">about company</li>
        </ul>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

both the parent page and the child page have nav-bar, they have the same assertive color and different title.
when swipe from child back to parent, the child page nav bar becomes blank,no title,no color. the parent page nav bar is normal.
the above situation only happens when swiping. 
Please help to check why?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you find the solution yet?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug on Ionic, now I solved it by adding a CSS class

```
ion-nav-bar.hide {
   display: block !important;
}
```

Remember that is a workaround, follow [this issue](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/5899) to tracking the fix.